# Python/Bloomberg API - Dynamic Security Screen

Tags: python, api, bloomberg

I work at a small investment firm which screens for certain market opportunities to approach (companies in distress) in a very manual and labor-intensive way by pulling down Bloomberg data into Excel. I want to create a Tableau-like API for the company with Python which can pull down a specific universe of CUSIPS (of all public U.S. companies) and order them based on the largest fall in their bond prices. Can someone reasonably estimate how long this will take to do using the Bloomberg/Python API. I've used Python before, but never with Bloomberg.

Comment: have you tried `pdblp`? https://pypi.org/project/pdblp/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you could easily create in BQuant (https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/bquantdemo/) which is based on Python but works directly in Bloomberg.

It allows you to create an interactive app and is more easily maintained because it's inside Bloomberg.